# Selected external URLs fetching in Apache Nutch 2.3.1

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

I have small seed with specific topic. I want that Nutch should only follow those external links that are expected to the related topic (It may be a heuristic only). How can I do it. If I have to write some plugin then what should be the extension point. Is there any example available for this.

Answer (score 0):

For your particular case you could give a try to the `parsefilter-naivebayes` plugin, you can find some more information about it in [NUTCH-2038](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/). Keep in mind that this is offered as a somehow general solution that somehow aligns with your use case. Of course, the reality could be different.

Nevertheless if you can come up with a good heuristic to detect when a link is a good candidate to follow you could implement that in a `HtmlParseFilter` and there you could choose which outlinks should be returned. Keep in mind that potentially at this stage the only information that you have about the possible outlink is the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Set your Nutch configuration nutch-default.xml

```
<property>
  <name>db.ignore.internal.links</name>
  <value>true</value>
  <description>If true, when adding new links to a page, links from
  the same host are ignored.  This is an effective way to limit the
  size of the link database, keeping only the highest quality
  links.
  </description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>db.ignore.external.links</name>
  <value>false</value>
  <description>If true, outlinks leading from a page to external hosts
  will be ignored. This is an effective way to limit the crawl to include
  only initially injected hosts, without creating complex URLFilters.
  </description>
</property>
```